# cannot access files in tomcat from another computer in the same network using ip address?

Tags: java, html, tomcat, ip-address

I installed tomcat 7 and deployed a file consisting of html files.
When I access it in my laptop using `localhost:8080/project` it worked.
And also when I typed (my IP at that instance) `192.168.1.26:8080/project` it also worked.

But when I access it from another laptop which is in the same network using `192.168.1.26:8080/project` I mean internet protocol address it shows error and can not connect. I want to access the html files on the another laptop. Suggest me a solution.

Comment: have you checked for firewalls on either computer? or between them?

Comment: "it shows error and can not connect" what error is it?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes computer firewall blocks access - try this
The firewall can be configured by: choosing the Windows Firewall from the Control Panel, then click on Exceptions -> Add Port and enter name and number: Tomcat, 8080 and leave transport protocol as TCP

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Tomact to listen to your machine local ip address(ex. 192.168.0.3).